# Running Apache on Windows without administrator priviledge when listening only on Localhost

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, windows-firewall

I try to deploy an custom Apache/Mysql/Php bundle to multiple Windows 8 laptop on non-administrator accounts. Apache will listen only to localhost incoming request. i.e. the user will run a browser to http://localhost.

Apache will not be run as a service, so no problem there.
The only issue I'm having is that Windows Firewall is blocking httpd.exe and asking to allow access which can only be done with a administrator account.

Put it another way : How can I bypass Windows Firewall as Apache will only be listening to internal incoming request from localhost ?

Mysql is running without issue on port 3306 with no firewall rules, and Windows Firewall did not block it, so I'm assuming that when listening to only localhost, Windows Firewall should not block the process, am I correct ?

It may be that my apache conf is not truly only listening to localhost : How can I make sure of that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `http.conf` file to see which port apache is listening to. You could search for `Listen` within that file.

I made Apache and MySQL run on my machin without admin rights. When Windows firewall was asking, if it is ok to run that process, I just hit "Cancel" - it worked anyway.

Make sure that no other applications are blocking the port apache is listening to.

Comment: You are right. This was indeed in http.conf "Listen" directive. I put `Listen 127.0.0.1:8080` and Windows Firewall did not ask again for UAC. I had to remeber to check both **http.conf** and **extra/httpd-vhost.conf**